# Merge an array with a 2d array to an array of objects, with the keys are the elements of the 1d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have 2 arrays like this

```
const dates = ["2019", "2020", "2021"];
const data = [[100, 200, 300, 20], [400, 500, 600, 30], [700, 800, 900, 40]];
```

I want to merge these 2 arrays into an array of objects like this
Details:
The first object of the result array will have the values of the first element of each array in the 2d array
The same goes with the rest of the result arrays

```
const result = [
 {
  2019: 100,
  2020: 400,
  2021: 700
 },
 {
  2019: 200,
  2020: 500,
  2021: 800
 },
 {
  2019: 300,
  2020: 600,
  2021: 900
 },
 {
  2019: 20,
  2020: 30,
  2021: 40
 }
]
```

Comment: You have 4 values in the inner 2d array and 3 for the object. So what do you want to do with the extra one?

Comment: @code basically the result array is for a bar chart, each object will be one group. So the first object will be a group of 3 bars. Hope it makes sense, sorry my English is not that great

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```js
const dates = ["2019", "2020", "2021"];
const data = [[100, 200, 300, 20], [400, 500, 600, 30], [700, 800, 900, 40]];

const res=data[0].reduce((a,_,j,da)=>{
  a.push(Object.fromEntries(dates.map((d,i)=>[d,data[i][j]])))
  return a;
},[]);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: nice one, but the result is missing the last element of the inner array in the 2d array

Comment: Please check again, I edited my code.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you first `transpose` your `data` rows then you can write `table` using `Array.prototype.map` and `Object.fromEntries` -

```js
const transpose = t =>
  t.some(a => Boolean(a.length))
    ? [t.map(a => a[0]), ...transpose(t.map(a => a.slice(1)))]
    : []
    
const table = (columns, rows) =>
  transpose(rows).map(r =>
    Object.fromEntries(columns.map((c,i) =>
      [c, r[i]]
    ))
  )

const dates = ["2019", "2020", "2021"]
const data = [[100, 200, 300, 20], [400, 500, 600, 30], [700, 800, 900, 40]]

console.log(table(dates, data))
```

Comment: nice one, but the result is missing the last element of the inner array in the 2d array

Comment: @Lucas i would recommend you first `transpose` the data rows. see my update for details